# Menu and SubMenu in different frames

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe

I have a little problem clicking on submenu, the reason is that the menu tag in one frame and the submenu in other so when i switch to other frame the submenu is invisible

My code:

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent().SwitchTo().Frame("top");

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement menuHoverLink = driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Cons"));
actions.MoveToElement(menuHoverLink);
actions.Build().Perform();

driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent().SwitchTo().Frame("content").FindElement(By.Id("elem3")).Click();
```

**Exception**

> Unexpected error. Element is not currently visible and so may not be
>   interacted with

does anyone have an idea what can i do in that case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution but it's not always will work
i just redirect to the url that comes after clicking the option.

```
string urlAfterClick = "..."

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(urlAfterClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use explicit wait

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("content");
WebDriverWaitwait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("elem3"))).Click();
```

Or to use send keys

```
actions.MoveToElement(menuHoverLink).Build().Perform();         
menuHoverLink.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
menuHoverLink.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: its stops being visible when you switch to content frame because you need to stay on Cons element sort of deadlock

Comment: @LeonBarkan I added another solution